# How can I receive action of PlayerNotificationManager notification button like stop?

Tags: android, android-notifications, exoplayer

I use Exoplayer and bind with PlayerNotificationManager to handle player action on the notification. It works fabulous but I want to get a listener or receiver when stop button pressed from notification. Right now when I click on the stop button player was stuck.

```
playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
        this,
        "playback_channel",
        R.string.exo_download_notification_channel_name,
        1,
        object : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
            override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player?): PendingIntent? {
                val intent = Intent(context, PlayerExoActivity::class.java)
                return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    1,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            }

            override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player?): String? {
                return "Day " + chapterName
            }

            override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player?): String {
                return courseName!!
            }

            override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
                player: Player?,
                callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback?
            ): Bitmap? {
                return largeIcon
            }
        }
    )
```

This is a receiver to handle other things while Exoplayer state change.

```
override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
        val intent = Intent("com.example.exoplayer.PLAYER_STATUS")
        intent.putExtra("state", PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_BUFFERING)
        broadcaster?.sendBroadcast(intent)
    } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
        val intent = Intent("com.example.exoplayer.PLAYER_STATUS")
        if (playWhenReady) {
            intent.putExtra("state", PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("state", PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED)
        }
        broadcaster?.sendBroadcast(intent)
    } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
        val intent = Intent("com.example.exoplayer.PLAYER_STATUS")
        intent.putExtra("state", PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED)
        broadcaster?.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution, I need to listen some buttons too?

Answer (score 4):

Create your own implementation of BroadcastReceiver:

```
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

  companion object {
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
      addAction(PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_NEXT)
      addAction(PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_PREVIOUS)
      addAction(PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_PAUSE)
      addAction(PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_STOP)
    }
  }

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    when (intent?.action) {
      PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_NEXT -> {
      }
      PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_PREVIOUS -> {
      }
      PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_PAUSE -> {
      }
      PlayerNotificationManager.ACTION_STOP -> {
          //do what you want here!!!
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then register:

```
registerReceiver(notificationReceiver, NotificationReceiver.intentFilter)
```

do not forget unregister it (avoid memory leaks):

```
unregisterReceiver(notificationReceiver)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late to answer but maybe it will help someone.

You can set custom ControlDispatcher for your playerNotificationManager. With ControlDispatcher you can control many of buttons of notification.

```
playerNotificationManager.setUseStopAction(true)
playerNotificationManager.setControlDispatcher(object : DefaultControlDispatcher() {
            override fun dispatchStop(player: Player, reset: Boolean): Boolean {
               //Do whatever you want on stop button click.
               Log.e("AudioPlayerService","Notification stop button clicked")
               return true
            }
         })
```

Answer (score -1):

first in your onCreate()

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    createPlayerNotificationManager();
    ....}
```

createPlayerNotificationManager()

```
   private void createPlayerNotificationManager() {
    playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, 151, "1234")
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public CharSequence getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                    return videoTitle;    // your video title
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public CharSequence getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                    if (!VideoPlayerActivity.this.isDestroyed()) {
                        Glide.with(VideoPlayerActivity.this)
                                .asBitmap()
                                .load(new File(mVideoFiles.get(position).getPath()))
                                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                                    }
                                });

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }).build();
    playerNotificationManager.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(this.getResources(), R.color.light_red, null));
    playerNotificationManager.setColorized(true);
    playerNotificationManager.setDefaults(151);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseFastForwardAction(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setUsePreviousAction(true);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseNextAction(true);
    playerNotificationManager.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseRewindAction(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        playerNotificationManager.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE);
    }
    playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dropdown_icon);
}
```

then in initPlayer()

```
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
```

in releasePlayer()

```
     playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
```